# Return a list of objects from firestore only once, NOT a stream. In Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I can add and update data in firestore, I can also retrieve a collection stream and turn it into a list of objects, BUT what I can't do is retrieve just a collection once and convert it into a list of objects.

//  Gets Stream from Firestore

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDataDateStream(String uid, int startDateTime, int endDateTime) {
    CollectionReference usersDataCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).collection('data');

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = dataCollection.where('dataDateTime', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDateTime).where('dataDateTime', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDateTime).snapshots();

    return snapshots;
  }
```

// Converts Stream to list

```
List<DataSavedModel> ListToday = List<DataSavedModel>();
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> dataSubToday;

 dataSubToday = db.getDataDateStream(appState.user.uid, startTimeToday, todayEndTime).listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      final List<DataSavedModel> ModelListToday = snapshot.documents.map((documentSnapshot) => DataSavedModel.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data)).toList();
      setState(() {
        this.ListToday = ModelListToday;
      });
    });
```

This works but I don't want to return a stream since I only want to retrieve the data once to iterate the list and perform actions on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [getDocuments()](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) to query the documents once on a Query or CollectionReference.

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("collection").getDocuments();
var list = querySnapshot.documents;
```

Comment: This gives only a list of documents, how can I convert that to a list of objects based on my data model. Like I did for the stream, second code block in my question.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you already have a line of code for that in your existing code where you're already working with a QuerySnapshot type object.